# Why isn't this image adjusting to the width size, if it is inside the container that I am specifying to width size?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to adjust all width sizes of inside the container. So all sides will be 80%. Why isn't the image adjusting as well? I'm expecting the image to not be so spread out to the right as it is now. I am expecting it to be aligned with everything else.

Here is the main HTML and CSS code attempting to do the above:

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>About me </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/300" />
  </div>
  <div class="intro column">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="skills column">
    <ul id="skill-list">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main_text">
    <p>
      Small batch wolf pug bicycle rights, letterpress kitsch Etsy listicle farm-to-table. Hoodie flannel Pitchfork normcore chambray, polaroid viral before they sold out. Wes Anderson skateboard single-origin coffee fixie shabby chic pour-over, four loko typewriter. Banksy American Apparel sartorial, irony XOXO plaid narwhal cred mumblecore keffiyeh asymmetrical sriracha. Marfa PBR lomo four loko aesthetic master cleanse, Pitchfork church-key bitters sartorial beard keffiyeh Thundercats. Mixtape aesthetic mustache readymade Blue Bottle, Banksy Wes Anderson Intelligentsia Kickstarter cliche biodiesel normcore farm-to-table polaroid narwhal. Semiotics mixtape Portland kale chips, heirloom Carles seitan pickled 3 wolf moon church-key master cleanse fingerstache.
    </p>
    <p>
      Tofu pork belly pug Tumblr crucifix. XOXO 3 wolf moon whatever, narwhal Vice Blue Bottle distillery PBR&B lumbersexual forage tattooed leggings 90's letterpress. Brooklyn pork belly umami hashtag gentrify tilde. Blog pork belly Godard mlkshk. Kitsch letterpress kale chips narwhal messenger bag. Migas farm-to-table banjo hella. Taxidermy lo-fi mlkshk normcore paleo DIY, tofu VHS lumbersexual ugh listicle.
    </p>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Comment: If you want the image to be as wide as its container, you'll have to specify in the css. The default width of an image is, ahem, the width of the image.

Comment: Why would you expect the image to magically resize?

Comment: @Beast_Code remove `image` class from `div` (You can complete remove that parent div of image) and set style to image: `<img style="width:100%;" src="..." />` .... and, for `p` You can add style `text-align:justify;`, just to be more nice :)

Comment: @MrLister I guess what i was expecting is for the image to stay within the boundaries of the container regardless of the size of the image.

Comment: @Beast_Code in that case, the answer is to use `max-width:100%` in the styles for the image instead of `width:100%`. That will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images with no style on them automatically default to their true size (ex. a 1400px by 300px image will be 1400px by 300px on the screen), as @MrLister said in his comment. You could do something like this:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

to set the image width to 100% of its parent's width.

Answer (score 1):

Width property isn't inherited. so the width of the container is 80% of its parent (the body element). but the width of the image is its true size.
To change its width add a css style.

```
img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

this changes its width to 100% of its parent (the container).

*performance note: It's better to change the size of the picture itself rather than use the width property because you download the whole picture then resize it which means useless data download.